A full embedding functor from $Sob$ to $Frm$?
In the following passage, the authors Picado and Pultr say the functor is a full embedding then they say that it would be a full embedding under some condition. Any explanation?


Is $\Omega$ the functor sending a topological space to its frame of opens?

@DaniëlApol yes exactly!

The covariant functors $\Omega\colon\mathrm{Sob}^\mathrm{op}\to\mathrm{Frm}$ and $\Omega\colon\mathrm{Sob}\to\mathrm{Frm}^\mathrm{op}=\mathrm{Loc}$, where the latter is the category of locales, are both full embeddings. In both cases, we are talking about the same functor, but we simply have multiple ways to write down the contravariant functor from sober spaces to frames in a covariant way. In principle, nothing is stopping you from talking about full embeddings that are contravariant functors, and then $\Omega\colon\mathrm{Sob}\to\mathrm{Frm}$ would be a full contravariant functor.
In practice however we write down contravariant functors as covariant ones by using opposite categories. When it comes to (full) embeddings, this becomes more than just notation, because subcategory inclusions are of course covariant, and you want to be able to think about embeddings as essentially being subcategory inclusions. This is why this book is asking full embeddings to be covariant functors.

Another tack to take is to define the category of locales to have frames as objects, and for its morphisms, right adjoints whose left adjoints preserve finite meets, i.e., "geometric morphisms" by analogy with the terminology used in topos theory. Psychologically, this may help impart a feeling of "concreteness" to locales. Then the full embedding $\mathrm{Sob}\to\mathrm{Loc}$ takes a continuous map $f: X \to Y$ to what might be denoted $\forall_f: \Omega(X) \to \Omega(Y)$, where $\forall_f(U)$ is the largest $V \in \Omega(Y)$ such that $f^{-1}(V) \subseteq U$.

@user43208 Good point!

@user43208 in the book of Picado and Pultr they define $\forall_f(U)=Y\setminus \overline{f(X\setminus U)}$, is this the largest $V$ such that $f^{-1}(V)\subseteq U$?

@Catalio13 Yes, because there is a chain of equivalences $$V \subseteq Y \setminus \overline{f(X \setminus U)} \Leftrightarrow \overline{f(X \setminus U)} \subseteq Y \setminus V \Leftrightarrow f(X \setminus U) \subseteq Y \setminus V \Leftrightarrow X \setminus U \subseteq f^{-1}(Y \setminus V) = X \setminus f^{-1}(V) \Leftrightarrow f^{-1}(V) \subseteq U$$ In the second equivalence we use the fact that $Y \setminus V$ is closed, and in the last steps we need to use the law of excluded middle. I chose my formulation so that it would hold constructively (if anyone cares about that).
